# Filtering duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, filter, count, duplicates

I am trying to "filter" some duplicates inside a table `locationrelation`. The table looks something like this:

```
+-----+---------+--------+----------------+--------------+
| id  | version | typeId | fromLocationId | toLocationId |
+-----+---------+--------+----------------+--------------+
|   1 |       0 |      1 |             77 |           76 |
|   2 |       0 |      1 |             78 |           76 |
|   3 |       0 |      1 |             79 |           76 |
|   4 |       0 |      1 |             80 |           76 |
|   5 |       0 |      1 |              2 |          240 |
|   6 |       0 |      1 |              3 |          240 |
|   7 |       0 |      1 |              4 |          240 |
|   8 |       0 |      1 |              5 |          240 |
|   9 |       0 |      1 |              6 |          240 |
|  10 |       0 |      1 |              7 |          240 |
----------------------------------------------------------
| 492 |       0 |      1 |              6 |        10000 |
```

I am trying to select only the `toLocationId` which is equal to 240 and appears only once. The problem is that I have some duplicates inside this table, as you can see in the last row. (`fromLocationId = 6` appears twice, one time it has `toLocationId=240`, and the second time has `toLocationId=1000`).

I've tried the following query:

```
select fromLocationId, toLocationId
from locationrelation
GROUP BY fromLocationId
HAVING COUNT(toLocationId) = 1;
```

, but the problem now is that it displays `toLocationId` with other value than 240. (see the last row)

Example:

```
+----------------+--------------+
| fromLocationId | toLocationId |
+----------------+--------------+
|              1 |          240 |
|              9 |          240 |
|             11 |          240 |
|             33 |          240 |
|             38 |          240 |
|             42 |          240 |
|             51 |          240 |
|             63 |          240 |
|             67 |          240 |
|             72 |          240 |
|             85 |          240 |
|             97 |          240 |
|             98 |          240 |
|            107 |          240 |
|            121 |          240 |
|            146 |          240 |
|            186 |          240 |
|            196 |          240 |
|            198 |          240 |
|            212 |          240 |
|            228 |          240 |
|            244 |          240 |
|            245 |          240 |
|            251 |          240 |
|            253 |          240 |
|            254 |          240 |
|            257 |          240 |
|            258 |          240 |
|          10000 |          240 |
|          10002 |          240 |
|          10003 |          240 |
|          10008 |          240 |
|          10015 |           67 |
+----------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind, I found the solution. A simple and would to the job, but I got an error first time when I used the `AND` operator. (maybe something wrong in the query)

```
select fromLocationId,toLocationId from locationrelation GROUP BY fromLocationId HAVING COUNT(toLocationId) = 1 and toLocationId = 240;
```

Comment: This query is invalid and will raise an error when you upgrade to a newer MySQL version.

Comment: @jarlh it all depends on the sql mode setting, just the default has been swapped to prevent such queries from happening as opposed to allow.

Comment: @Tr909: you do not even need the group by, just a where clause to filter if the above solution works for you.